# Display results in two columns

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an array that has three properties
Image
Name
Date

I would like to display this in two columns instead of in a table view which only gives me one column. How can I do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `UITableViewCell` - e.g. `MyUITableViewCell`, then add two `UILable`s to your new cell.
Place them as you wish (e.g. each half the cell's width, one aligning left, one aligning right).

Then your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in the `UITableView`'s dataSource, instead of creating a new instance of `UITableViewCell`, create an instance of `MyUITableViewCell` and set the two `UILable`s' texts to the data you want to display.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use interface builder, you can just layout the views you want inside a UITableViewCell, tag them with different numbers and then use something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) getCellContentView:(NSString *)cellIdentifier {

    NSArray* nibViews =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCells" owner:self options:nil];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [nibViews objectAtIndex:1];

    return cell;

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Account *acc = [accountManager.accounts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UILabel *title = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *counters = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:3];

    title.text = acc.title;
    counters.text = [acc statusText];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only `rows` and `sections` in iPhone development. If you need columns, you should add the image, name and date as `subviews` to your `UITableViewCell`

```
UITableViewCell *cell ; //  allocate this
[cell addSubview: comboView]; // where comboView has 3 views in it.
```